# Paypal Express checkout not showing up on cart page

Tags: paypal, ce-1.9.1.0, paypal-express

The paypal express checkout button not showing up on my cart pages. It shows up as a payment method on my checkout page however and works fine. I enabled the Display on Shopping Cart option even going down to the store view and trying and still a no go. I even tried putting my theme to default one and it still does not show up.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Paypal was disabled in the modules xml files. The strangest thing do is it still worked as a payment method in the checkout but the shortcut want working on cart pages. I dont know how that happened but enabling it again fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the following xml in your paypal.xml layout:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart.top_methods">
        <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express.top" before="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml">
            <action method="setIsQuoteAllowed"><value>1</value></action>
            <action method="setShowOrPosition"><value>after</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="checkout.cart.methods">
        <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express.bottom" before="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml">
            <action method="setIsQuoteAllowed"><value>1</value></action>
            <action method="setShowOrPosition"><value>after</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <update handle="SHORTCUT_popup" />
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Also make sure you clear Magento cache so that the changes can reflect.

If that doesn't work, enable Magento logging and go to the cart page. If it does not display, check exception.log for any Paypal gateway issues.

Comment: I checked the xml file and those are in there so that should be fine. Looking at my logs files there are no errors to report. I dont know why its not showing up. I have a staging site where its showing up perfectly fine so Im lost.

Comment: Is this on the live site? Whats the url so we can check

Comment: Actually just fixed it thanks very much tho!